# REST request from app works, but not from javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, cross-domain

I'm building an app that has to get and set data at a remote web service through requests. When I use the jQuery GET request it works fine, I can request data from the service without any problems, but when I use PUT I get some erros:

> OPTIONS http://myurl.com 501 (Unsupported method
>   ('OPTIONS'))
>
> OPTIONS http://myurl.com Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I've tried almost anything to get this to work, but it won't work. I've download a chrome app called REST Console, which can make custom REST requests. The strange thing is that I can interact with my server over that app but not through my javascript!

This is the javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://myurl.com',
    type: 'PUT',
    data: '<time>16:00</time>',
    success: function(data) { alert(data); }
});
```

Could anybody tell me what is going on here?

Comment: is the address u are hosting something like- `file:///Drive:`

Comment: yeah, but I have tried with xampp  and that gives the same erors

Answer (score 0):

First ensure you're serving the page that runs the script from a web server, not directly from the file system.

I'm guessing your service at `http://myurl.com` is at a different host name to the host name your page is being served from? For it to work in this case you need to implement HTTP headers to support [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://enable-cors.org/).

Your service at `http://myurl.com` needs to handle an HTTP `OPTIONS` request, the response to which should be a set of HTTP headers (with no content) as follows:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://url-of-page-with-javascript/`

Optionally you can also specify `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`, `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`. See the [full specification here](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

You'll also need to add the same headers with the same values when your server responds to the `PUT` request - obviously the content will also be included with this response.